# LinqToXml: reorder user nodes based on mangerial hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a output xml from LDAP(active Directory) of users with their managers as shown below.  I need to reorder the users so that when creating users i create them in order of the managerial hierarchy. the dn field in the user and the manager subnode are the linking values. This is so that when they are processed by our user import routine, we don't have to cater for assigning a manager to a user when the manager hasn't been created yet. Is this possible with Linqtoxml?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<syncdata>
    <users> 
        <user>
            <dn>User2</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User1</dn></manager>
        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User1</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User5</dn></manager>
        </user>  
        <user>
            <dn>User4</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User1</dn></manager>
        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User5</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User3</dn></manager>
        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User3</dn>   
            <manager><dn></dn></manager>
        </user>
    </users>
</syncdata>
```

UPDATE: reformatted the xml as the suggestions worked partially. and it was previously invalid as there was a circular reference.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do - create new xml or parse this one. Also please show what you have tried so far

Comment: updated the question, the dn nodes are the unique values and the managers are links to the users managerid similar to the results of a sql select query i.e. select userid,managerid from users

Comment: You wrote a comment below that seems to be for my answer, but which was written under another answer - I'll answer you here anyway, so I know you (and others) will see it: Seems I misunderstood your question earlier. I've updated my answer, hope this is closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var element = XElement.Load(yourXmlPath);

    var ordered=element.Element("users").Elements().OrderBy(u => u.Element("manager").Element("dn").Value);

    element.Element("users").ReplaceAll(ordered);
```

Comment: @kjartan thanks for the help but with the updated xml, it doesn't correctly reorder ie the new order should be user3,user5,user1, and then user4 and user2. the order i get returned is 3,2,4,5,1 but user2's manager is user 1 for example

Answer (score 1):

This option will give you a sorted `IOrderedEnumerable`, with the xml for each user, and the managerId separately. Variations of this should give you a lot of flexibility:

```
var sortedUsers =
     yourRootXElement.Element("users")
                     .Elements()
                     .Select(usr => 
                               new {
                                     managerId = usr.Element("manager")
                                                    .Element("dn")
                                                    .Value, 
                                     user = usr
                                    }) 
                     .OrderBy(user => user.managerId);
```

**Update:**

Based on a comment under one of the other answers, it seems you want to reorder this "recursively" (sort of).

Initially, I don't that is very easy using Linq - Unless you have the option of manipulating your original XML, you might be better of writing a recursive algorithm for this.

If however, you can add a field `depth` to each user in your XML, so that it would look something like this..:

```
<syncdata>
    <users> 
        <user>
            <dn>User2</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User1</dn></manager>
            <depth>2</depth>

        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User1</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User5</dn></manager>
            <depth>1</depth>
        </user>  
        <user>
            <dn>User4</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User1</dn></manager>
            <depth>2</depth>
        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User5</dn>   
            <manager><dn>User3</dn></manager>
            <depth>1</depth>
        </user>
        <user>
            <dn>User3</dn>   
            <manager><dn></dn></manager>
            <depth>0</depth> <!-- Note: Root element in hierarchy! -->
        </user>
    </users>
</syncdata>
```

...then you could perhaps order it as follows?:

```
var sortedUsers =
    yourRootXElement.Element("users")
                    .Elements()
                    .Select(usr => 
                                new {
                                    userId =  usr.Element("dn").Value,
                                    managerId = usr.Element("manager")
                                                   .Element("dn")
                                                   .Value,
                                    depth = usr.Element("depth")
                                               .Value,
                                    userData = usr
                                })
                    .OrderBy(user => user.depth)
                    .ThenBy(user => user.managerId);
```

**Note:** This should order them by their "reporting-levels" in the hierarchy, but will not show those under a manager listed under him - ie.: All those reporting to a top-level managers will be shown first, followed by all those reporting to a second-level managers, etc...

Comment: Yes i believe your right i need to stamp the user nodes with a depth via a recursive function and then i should be able to order. just trying to workout how i can do that

Comment: @Tim If you could get the depth in the original XML, that would be best (I have no idea if LDAP can provide that for you..?). Otherwise, if you're going to use a recursive function anyway, I would assume you might as well list the data out directly from it, instead of just using it to generate a "depth stamp"? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot get the depth in the initial file, as its a format for importing users which supports LDAP and other sources. I can preprocess the file though and recursively increment a new depth value, I just need to workout how to do this ;)